# has_one :through polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphism, has-many-through

I have these models and associations. I want to reach roleable trough privilege model doesnt matter what roleable_type is(Dj or Photographer)? Use join model because privilege model will have other attributes. It is possible something like this:

```
class User
  has_one :privilege, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :roleable, through: :privilege
end

class Dj < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :privilege
  has_one :user, through: :privilege, as: :roleable
end

class Photographer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :privilege
  has_one :user, through: :privilege, as: :roleable
end

class Privilege < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :roleable, polymorphic: true
end
```

If i add source_type: 'Dj' to has_many :through return only with roleable_type 'Dj'. I want to do this bellow:

```
u = User.first
u.roleable #return privilage roleable( doesnt matter Dj or Photograher)
```

Comment: You need a Roleable class as well if you're making a join table. Did you write one yet?

Comment: i want roleable to be Dj or Photograph model

Comment: Ah ok it sounds like you should be doing inherited classes. So instead of Photographer and DJ inheriting from ActiveRecord::Base, have them inherit from a class called Roleable. `class Photographer < Roleable`. Then you still have to make a `roleable.rb` file. And you could put all your shared methods in this as well. If this is what you want, you wouldn't need tables for photographer or DJ. just a table that represents Roleable.

Comment: i will need dj and photographer tables because will contain different methods and attributes

Comment: Ok so `u.roleable` could potentially return a Photgrapher object? What does it return now?

Comment: raise error about :source_type, but source_type can be only dj or photographer

Comment: Ah ok what's your schema look like for Roleable? Why the word `source`, where it should be `roleable_type` ?

Comment: i want rolable to be Dj or Photohraphic that is added as: :roleable

Answer (score -1):

I'd make those `belongs_to`, not that that changes anything.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :privilege, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :roleable, through: :privilege
end

class Dj < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :privilege
  belongs_to :user, through: :privilege, as: :roleable
end

class Photographer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :privilege
  belongs_to :user, through: :privilege, as: :roleable
end

class Privilege < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :roleable, polymorphic: true
end
```

Can you post, what `u.roleable` returns?

Comment: hm belongs_to dont support :through

Comment: What would `has_one :privilege ; belongs_to :something, through: :privilege` mean? This is ... either a circular relationship or a nonsensical one